# Forms and views for custom User model with extra parameters [django 2.1]

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Im trying to create a form that would allow me to add a profile picture to the custom User object. I know that there is OneToOne method, although I want it to be stored directly in User.

Comment: I'm new on stackoverflow, so once someone provides me with an answer should I edit my question to include my own solution or just accept the correct answer?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

Comment: question should be left just question. If some answer solves your question you can accept it. Also if you found another solution too for the problem, you can also answer your own question, so that other users who in future might have the same question can see both answers and choose whats best for them.. Editing the question to include solution can create confusion about what the question originally was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend default User Model like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    """Add more fields to default user model."""

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True, null=True)
```

Now you need to edit your settings.py to make your custom User model the default auth model. Add this line in your settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myApp.User'
```

myApp is the name of app in whose models.py your created your Custom User Model.
And that's all, now the default auth model is your custom model `User` which is exactly the same as the Django default auth model except it has an additional field `profile_pic` to store an image.

Form to add picture should be like this:

```
class profilepictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form to add profile picture to User model."""

    class Meta:
        """Meta class for profilepictureForm."""

        model = User
        fields = ('profile_pic', )
```

And in your views you should use this form like this:

```
def add_profile_picture(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = profilepictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = profilepictureForm(instance=request.user)
        return render(request, 'userpanel/profilepicture.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: `from .models import User`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on below code

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm

# Imaginary function to handle an uploaded file.
from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

For more information please check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/